# How do I utilize Row_Number() (partitioning) for my datapool correctly

Tags: sql-server, row-number

we have following table (output is already ordered and separated for understanding):

```
| PK | FK1 | FK2 |   ActionCode |         CreationTS  | SomeAttributeValue |
+----+-----+-----+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|  6 | 100 | 500 |       Create | 2011-01-02 00:00:00 |                  H |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 | 100 | 500 |       Change | 2011-01-01 02:00:00 |                  Z |
|  2 | 100 | 500 |       Change | 2011-01-01 01:00:00 |                  X |
|  1 | 100 | 500 |       Create | 2011-01-01 00:00:00 |                  Y |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4 | 100 | 510 |       Create | 2011-01-01 00:30:00 |                  T |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5 | 100 | 520 | CreateSystem | 2011-01-01 00:30:00 |                  A |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what is `ActionCode`? we use this in `c#` and there it represents an enum-value

what do i want to achieve?

well, i need the following output:

```
| FK1 | FK2 |   ActionCode | SomeAttributeValue |
+-----+-----+--------------+--------------------+
| 100 | 500 |       Create |                  H |
| 100 | 500 |       Create |                  Z |
| 100 | 510 |       Create |                  T |
| 100 | 520 | CreateSystem |                  A |
-------------------------------------------------
```

well, what is the actual logic?
we have some logical groups for composite-key (FK1 + FK2). each of these groups can be broken into partitions, which begin with `Create` or `CreateSystem`. each partition ends with `Create`, `CreateSystem` or `Change`. The actual value of `SomeAttributeValue` for each partition should be the value from the last line of the partition.

it is not possible to have following datapool:

```
| PK | FK1 | FK2 |   ActionCode |         CreationTS  | SomeAttributeValue |
+----+-----+-----+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|  7 | 100 | 500 |       Change | 2011-01-02 02:00:00 |                  Z |
|  6 | 100 | 500 |       Create | 2011-01-02 00:00:00 |                  H |
|  2 | 100 | 500 |       Change | 2011-01-01 01:00:00 |                  X |
|  1 | 100 | 500 |       Create | 2011-01-01 00:00:00 |                  Y |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and then expect PK 7 to affect PK 2 or PK 6 to affect PK 1.

i don't even know how/where to start ... how can i achieve this?
we are running on mssql 2005+

**EDIT:**
there's [a dump](http://store.niedermair.name/stackoverflow/dump/6277511.csv) available:

- instanceId: my PK
- tenantId: FK 1
- campaignId: FK 2
- callId: FK 3
- refillCounter: FK 4
- ticketType: ActionCode (1 & 4 & 6 are `Create`, 5 is `Change`, 3 must be ignored)
- ticketType, profileId, contactPersonId, ownerId, handlingStartTime, handlingEndTime, memo, callWasPreselected, creatorId, creationTS, changerId, changeTS should be taken from the `Create` (first line in partition in groups)
- callingState, reasonId, followUpDate, callingAttempts and callingAttemptsConsecutivelyNotReached should be taken from the last `Create` (which then would be a "one-line-partition-in-group" / the same as the upper one) or `Change` (last line in partition in groups)

Comment: Please elaborate on the last rowset. What do you mean by "affect"? In any case,  couldn't this rowset be partitioned so as to have PKs 1 & 2 in one partition and PKs 6 & 7 in the other one? Up to that point everything seemed clear, but that last bit somewhat confused me.

Comment: @Andriy M: affect: the value of `SomeAttributeValue` should not be taken! ... yes, it could be partitioned to PK 1&2 and PK 6&7 - but how? we do not store a `lastPK`-value in a line ... that's why i described the logic, which i wasn't able to translate to mssql. to sum it up: the partitions can not be created by any `lastPK`-columns - just with the ordering (and the logic described)

Comment: Thank you, I think I've got it. And one more question, please, about `…partitions, which begin with…` and `…partition ends with…`. When you say `begin` or `end`, you sort of imply a certain order. You even said in the beginning, `output is already ordered`. Now, what order is it? From how you've presented the data, I could assume that the order is by `FK1, FK2, CreationTS`. Is that actually so?

Comment: @aAndriy M: you are correct - the ordering is done this way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that each partition can only contain a *single* Create or CreateSystem, otherwise your requirements are ill-defined. The following is untested, since I don't have a sample table, nor sample data in an easily consumed format:

```
;With Partitions as (
     Select
         t1.FK1,
         t1.FK2,
         t1.CreationTS as StartTS,
         t2.CreationTS as EndTS
     From
         Table t1
             left join
         Table t2
             on
                  t1.FK1 = t2.FK1 and
                  t1.FK2 = t2.FK2 and
                  t1.CreationTS < t2.CreationTS and
                  t2.ActionCode in ('Create','CreateSystem')
             left join
         Table t3
             on
                  t1.FK1 = t3.FK1 and
                  t1.FK2 = t3.FK2 and
                  t1.CreationTS < t3.CreationTS and
                  t3.CreationTS < t2.CreationTS and
                  t3.ActionCode in ('Create','CreateSystem')
       where
           t1.ActionCode in ('Create','CreateSystem') and
           t3.FK1 is null
), PartitionRows as (
     SELECT
         t1.FK1,
         t1.FK2,
         t1.ActionCode,
         t2.SomeAttributeValue,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION_FRAGMENT_ID BY t1.FK1,T1.FK2,t1.StartTS ORDER BY t2.CreationTS desc) as rn
     from
         Partitions t1
             inner join
         Table t2
             on
                t1.FK1 = t2.FK1 and
                t1.FK2 = t2.FK2 and
                t1.StartTS <= t2.CreationTS and
                (t2.CreationTS < t1.EndTS or t1.EndTS is null)
)
select * from PartitionRows where rn = 1
```

(Please note than I'm using all kinds of reserved names here)

The basic logic is: The Partitions CTE is used to define each partition in terms of the FK1, FK2, an inclusive start timestamp, and exclusive end timestamp. It does this by a triple join to the base table. the rows from `t2` are selected to occur after the rows from `t1`, then the rows from `t3` are selected to occur between the matching rows from `t1` and `t2`. Then, in the WHERE clause, we exclude any rows from the result set where a match occurred from `t3` - the result being that the row from `t1` and the row from `t2` represent the start of two adjacent partitions.

The second CTE then retrieves all rows from `Table` for each partition, but assigning a `ROW_NUMBER()` score within each partition, based on the `CreationTS`, sorted descending, with the result that `ROW_NUMBER()` 1 within each partition is the last row to occur.

Finally, within the select, we choose those rows that occur last within their respective partitions.

This does all assume that `CreationTS` values are distinct within each partition. I may be able to re-work it using PK also, if that assumption doesn't hold up.

Comment: first of all: THANK YOU! ... this sounds promising ... but, there's a little mistake in it: `t1` lacks `creationTS` when doing the `ROW_NUMBER` inside `PartitionRows`. btw ... i've edited my question and provided some sample data with format-description - maybe this could give you a deeper insight!

Comment: @Andreas - you're right, it should have been StartTS, not CreationTS.

Answer (score 0):

It is solvable with a recursive CTE. Here (assuming rows within partitions are ordered by `CreationTS`):

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FK1, FK2 ORDER BY CreationTS)
  FROM data
),
subgroups AS (
  SELECT
    PK, FK1, FK2, ActionCode, CreationTS, SomeAttributeValue, rn,
    Subgroup = 1,
    Subrank  = 1
  FROM partitioned
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    p.PK, p.FK1, p.FK2, p.ActionCode, p.CreationTS, p.SomeAttributeValue, p.rn,
    Subgroup = s.Subgroup + CASE p.ActionCode WHEN 'Change' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    Subrank  = CASE p.ActionCode WHEN 'Change' THEN s.Subrank ELSE 0 END + 1
  FROM partitioned p
    INNER JOIN subgroups s ON p.FK1 = s.FK1 AND p.FK2 = s.FK2
      AND p.rn = s.rn + 1
),
finalranks AS (
  SELECT
    PK, FK1, FK2, ActionCode, CreationTS, SomeAttributeValue, rn,
    Subgroup, Subrank,
    rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FK1, FK2, Subgroup ORDER BY Subrank DESC)
    /* or: rank = MAX(Subrank) OVER (PARTITION BY FK1, FK2, Subgroup) - Subrank + 1 */
  FROM subgroups
)
SELECT PK, FK1, FK2, ActionCode, CreationTS, SomeAttributeValue
FROM finalranks
WHERE rank = 1
```

Comment: thanks for helping! ... unfortunately the execution-time ... well ... sucks like hell. the table contains 8.595 lines only - i aborted the select on `subgroups` after 4 minutes having 9.281 lines...

Comment: dah ... another slapya ... i had a wrong expected result in my question - i've corrected it now ... sorry!

Comment: @Andreas: I'd expect an index on `data (FK1, FK2, CreationTS)` to improve the performance considerably. Alternatively, an index on `data (FK1, FK2, CreationTS) INCLUDE (ActionCode, SomeAttributeValue)` might improve it even further.

Comment: @Andreas: Actually, my query would return all the columns. (I mean, all those presented in your initial example table.) If some of them are not needed, you can just remove them from the final SELECT.

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the fact that when you aborted the query the output had more rows than the original table. Strange...

Comment: @Andreas: Maybe I'm missing some crucial details about your schema, which might require some modifications to my solution. I would be interested to try my solution on more or less real data. Do you think you could fetch some subset for me? Upload it somewhere maybe?

Comment: @Andriy M: well, i've added the suggested index on `(FK1, FK2, CreationTS)`. now i've executed a select on `subgroups` again - aborted after 3 minutes having 8.657 lines ... a bit better, but not really practicable for production code :(

Comment: @Andriy M: i've provided a dump and a description ... thanks for helping!